# Android Room: Query returns null in inherited field

Tags: android, android-room

I'm currently refactoring my project to use Room Persistence Library (loving it by the way), but I've run into a problem where I'm querying my database for a pojo that inherits from an Entity-class. The fields in the super class is for some reason not being loaded with data from the query.

Heres my class (btw. this is a customized class, not the real one, as I can't share the real sourcecode):

Task.java:

```
public class Task extends SyncEntity {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public final long taskId;

    public final String title;

     /** Status of the given task.
     * Enumerated Values: 0 (Active), 1 (Inactive), 2 (Completed)
     */
    @TypeConverters(StatusConverter.class)
    public final Status status;

    @TypeConverters(DateConverter.class)
    public Date startDate;

    public Task(@NonNull String taskId,
                   @NonNull String title,
                   @NonNull Status status,
                   @NonNull Date startDate,
                   @NonNull Long createdAt,
                   @Nullable Long updatedAt,
                   @Nullable Boolean deleted) {
        super(createdAt, updatedAt, deleted);
        this.taskId = taskId;
        this.title = title;
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Ignore
    public Task(@NonNull Builder builder) {
        super(builder);
        this.taskId = builder.taskId;
        this.title = builder.title;
        this.status = builder.status;
    }

    ...
    ** left out for brevity **

}
```

and my query:

```
@Dao
public interface TaskRepository {

    @Query("SELECT " +
            "taskId, " +
            "title, " +
            "status, " +
            "startDate, " +
            "created_at AS createdAt, " +
            "updated_at AS updatedAt " +
            "FROM tasks " +
            "WHERE status = 0 " +
            "AND deleted = 0")
    LiveData<List<Task>> getActiveTasks();
    ...
    ** left out for brevity **
}
```

The query return a result where createdAt is null, which it shouldn't be, as all SyncEntities defaults createdAt to System.currentTimeMillis() and I've doublechecked that the value is present in the database.

I'm also getting the following warning when compiling, but I don't understand why:

> Warning:(33, 33) The query returns some columns [createdAt, updatedAt]
>   which are not use by com.example.project.data.models.entities.Task.
>   You can use @ColumnInfo annotation on the fields to specify the
>   mapping. com.example.project.data.models.entities.Task has some
>   fields [created_at, updated_at, deleted] which are not returned by the
>   query. If they are not supposed to be read from the result, you can
>   mark them with @Ignore annotation. You can suppress this warning by
>   annotating the method with
>   @SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.CURSOR_MISMATCH). Columns returned by
>   the query: taskId, title, status, startDate, createdAt, updatedAt.
>   Fields in com.example.project.data.models.entities.Task:
>   created_at, updated_at, deleted, taskId, title, status, startDate.

Here's my super-class:
SynEntity.java

```
@Entity
public class SyncEntity implements Syncable {

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "created_at")
    public final Long createdAt;

    @Nullable
    @ColumnInfo(name = "updated_at")
    public final Long updatedAt;

    @Nullable
    public final Boolean deleted;

    SyncEntity(@NonNull Long createdAt,
               @Nullable Long updatedAt,
               @Nullable Boolean deleted) {
            this.createdAt = createdAt;
            this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
            this.deleted = deleted == null ? false : deleted;
    }

    @Ignore
    SyncEntity(@NonNull Builder<?> builder) {
            this.createdAt = builder.createdAt;
            this.updatedAt = builder.updatedAt;
            this.deleted = builder.deleted;
    }

    public static class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> {

        @NonNull
        private Long createdAt = System.currentTimeMillis();
        @Nullable
        private Long updatedAt = null;
        @NonNull
        private Boolean deleted = false;

        public Builder() {}

    ...
    ** left out for brevity **

}
```

Is this a bug in Room or intended behavior?

Comment: Excellent suggestion. Didn't think of that. Just checking... To who ever posted the comment that is now deleted?!?

Comment: it was me, but since you were ignoring it for more than 15 minutes i though you dont care so i deleted that comment

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't mean to, but was away for a meeting.

Comment: You've actually led me to an answer.

Comment: so what was wrong? `created_at AS createdAt` ? it should be just `created_at` ?

Comment: I will accept your comment as the answer in this case. Just post it as an answer.

Comment: Its a bug. I will write up what i've found out. But this will take a while.

Comment: The problem lies in that the code uses a underscore ("_") in the @ColumnInfo created_at and updated_at fields.

Comment: ok, i thought you dont need that `AS` (since you have `@ColumnInfo`) but it seems i was wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**
As @pskink pointed out in the comments, the problem is the query.

The problem lies in the query:

```
@Override
public LiveData<List<UserPet>> loadUserAndPetNames() {
    final String _sql = "SELECT users.firstName AS firstName, 
    users.lastName AS lastName, pets.name AS petName, pets.created_at 
    AS createdAt, pets.updated_at AS updatedAt, pets.deleted AS deleted 
    FROM users, pets WHERE users.userId = pets.user_id";
    final RoomSQLiteQuery _statement = RoomSQLiteQuery.acquire(_sql, 0);
```

The query returns column name as "createdAt" but the Entity's field is explicitly annotated with "created_at" so they don't match.

Comment: ok i didnt have time to check your sample project but it seems that if you replace `"created_at AS createdAt, updated_at AS updatedAt "` with `"created_at, updated_at "` it should simply work, what do you need that `AS` aliases for?

Comment: You're right. Don't know how I could miss that. I think I even tried that, but must have forgotten to run the test.

Comment: this is because you have `@ColumnInfo` annotation which basically says: "if your database column name is different that your entity field name then specify it here but in db queries use always database columns and we will know how to map database column to entity field"

Comment: You should add that as an answer

Comment: Thanks for your help